# Where to find TRANSFORM GROUP in a DB2 function metadata?

Tags: db2

I need to generate myself DDL for DB2 external functions as SYSCAT.ROUTINES does not provide TEXT for external functions.
I do know that DB2 is not aware of external function body code. But still, external functions have DDL used to create them.
In case of regular functions SYSCAT.ROUTINES.TEXT contains entire DDL script rather than just function body.
Unfortunately for me TEXT for external functions is not filled with their DDL.
In order to generate DDL myself I try to gather all the pieces spread over different metadata columns and tables.
I cannot find so far TRANSFORM GROUP I need to specify sometimes in DDL as described here.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-function-external-scalar
There is no such field in SYSCAT.ROUTINES. Where in the metadata am I supposed to look for it?

I asked the question at the DB2 community forum. Got no answser so far.

Comment: Do you mean this view or how it is referenced? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscattransforms

Comment: I mean how to figure out what transform group is specified (if any) for a DB2 external function to build the full DDL for the function.
So, in your terms, I guess, how "syscat.transforms is referenced by syscat.routines". Or rather the question is how to link syscat.routines to syscat.transforms if the transform is specified for a particular function.

Comment: TRANSFORM GROUP group-name
Indicates the transform group to be used for user-defined structured type transformations when invoking the function. A transform is required if the function definition includes a user-defined structured type as either a parameter or returns data type. If this clause is not specified, the default group name DB2_FUNCTION is used...